# How to show(or not) a checkbox dynamically depending on another form value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My objective is to create a checkbox on this form, but only show it depending on the value of a dropdown list.

```
{
    //this is the drop down list value
    key: false, label: 'T.Expediente', name: 'COD_DPTO_ORIGEN', editable: true,
    edittype: 'select', /*editoptions: { value: $scope.settings.cbGridCodTipExpOp },*/ formatter: 'select', width: 5,
    editrules: { required: false }, editoptions: { 'class': 'bg-required' },
                },
{
    //and this is the checkbox I had to create
    key: false, label: 'Colaborativo', name: 'FLAG_COLABORATIVO', hidden: true, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
    formoptions: { label: '¿Colaborativo?' },
    editrules: { edithidden: true },
    editoptions: { value: "1:0", defaultValue: "0" },
},
```

The checkbox should only be shown when the value of the dropdown list is "13".

This form appears when the user decides to add a new register to a certain table.

Sorry I've changed some things because I can't show it, but they don't have anything to do with my question

```
showNavGrid: true,      // Muestra o no Navgrid.
navTools: { add: true, edit: true, del: true, view: true, refresh: true, search: false },
prmAdd: {
    closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true,
    id: 'ROWID',
    url: AtUrlValue.XXXXXXXXX
    editData: { __RequestVerificationToken: $rootScope.sAntiForToken },
    beforeShowForm: function (form) {

        $('#xxxxxx', form).show();
        $('#xxxxxx', form).hide();
        $('#xxxxxx', form).attr("disabled", false);
        $('#tr_' + 'xxxx', form).hide();


        //THIS is what i've tried
        if ( $('#COD_DPTO_ORIGEN').val() == "13" ) {
            $('#tr_FLAG_COLABORATIVO', form).show();
            }
        else {
            $('#tr_FLAG_COLABORATIVO', form).hide();
            }

    },
```

It does work the way I did it but it only enters the if when the page loads, as it's on the event `beforeShowForm`. But I don't know how to make it dynamically, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the change event in the list

```
$(document).on('change', '#tr_FLAG_COLABORATIVO', function(e){
  //add your code
});
```